# Converting a python string index to a datetime one

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am importing some data that has one column for date and another for the hour. I would like to combine them into a single DateTime column.

I have used

```
df2 = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path,
              parse_dates=[['Date', 'Hour']],
              infer_datetime_format=True)
```

which has returned

```
      Date_Hour    Unnamed: 0      Data
0   2018-01-01 0         3         51.29
1   2018-01-01 1         4         43.59    
2   2018-01-01 2         5         93.60    
3   2018-01-01 3         6         54.78    
4   2018-01-01 4         7         14.35
```

but the column Date_Hour is not in the DateTime format, and when I try to convert it I get an error

```
df2.set_index('Date_Hour', inplace=True)
pd.to_datetime(df2.index)
```

gives

```
ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', '2018-01-01 0')
```

I have also tried using

```
pd.to_datetime(prices.index, format='%y-%m-%d %H')
```

The data that I have imported looks like this;

```
 ,Date,Hour,Data
3,2018-01-01,0,51.29
4,2018-01-01,1,43.59
5,2018-01-01,2,93.60
6,2018-01-01,3,54.78
7,2018-01-01,4,14.35
8,2018-01-01,5,18.60
```

And I would like the output to be

```
                          Data
 Date_Hour
2018-01-01 00:00         51.29
2018-01-01 01:00         43.59  
2018-01-01 02:00         93.60  
2018-01-01 03:00         54.78  
2018-01-01 04:00         14.35
```

Comment: what is your desired o/p?

Comment: I will update the question, but it is to have an index that is of the DateTime format

Comment: what's the expected format of `Date_Hour` ?

Comment: No, an index is for a different purpose.

Comment: @LukaVlaskalic Did my answer solve your question?

Comment: @Scotty1- yes thank you, I had to wait a certain number of minutes before accepting, which is why I just upvoted before.

Comment: You are welcome and no problem at all. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case the missing leading `0` of the hour is problematic. You can avoid this importing without parsing to `datetime` and then using `zfill` before parsing to `datetime`:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path)
df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.Date + df2.Hour.astype(str).str.zfill(2), format='%Y-%m-%d%H')
```

To drop the `Date` and `Hour` columns after parsing them:

```
df2.drop(['Date' ,'Hour'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Short explanation:
`zfill` will pad the numeric string with zeros up the the specified number of characters.

Of course you can also specify a `date_parser` for `pd.read_csv`, but in this case it is imho much clearer and more pythonic to parse the dates after reading the csv.

Comment: I suspect that this is faster than casting to Timedelta (the route I went in my answer)

Comment: Yep, it definitively is. :) Especially looping over all values with `apply` will slow down the parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: a few answers **greatly** improved on my first crack at this. I'm going to leave this up since it is referenced in another answer.

Let's start with setting the dates to datetime type.

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], unit="ms")
```

We want to add hours to that so they need to be `Timedelta`.

```
df["Hour"] = df["Hour"].apply(lambda x: pd.Timedelta(hours=int(x)))
```

Now a simple sum:

```
df["Date_hour"] = df["Date"] + df["Hour"]
```

Set a datetime index the same way you would any other column of datetime dtype:

```
df = df.set_index("Date_hour")
```

Comment: `df["Hour"] = df["Hour"].apply(lambda x: pd.Timedelta(hours=int(x)))` could be simplified with `df["Hour"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["Hour"], unit='h')`

Answer (score 1):

[Charles Landau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10553976/charles-landau) was close. Just some changes

```
df

      sr          Date  Hour     Data
0      3    2018-01-01     0    51.29
1      4    2018-01-01     1    43.59
2      5    2018-01-01     2    93.60
3      6    2018-01-01     3    54.78
4      7    2018-01-01     4    14.35
5      8    2018-01-01     5    18.60


df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], unit="ns")
df["Hour"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["Hour"])
df["Date_Hour"]=(df["Date"] + df["Hour"]).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
df.set_index("Date_Hour")

                    sr        Date  Hour     Data
       Date_Hour                
2018-01-01 00:00     3  2018-01-01     0    51.29
2018-01-01 01:00     4  2018-01-01     1    43.59
2018-01-01 02:00     5  2018-01-01     2    93.60
2018-01-01 03:00     6  2018-01-01     3    54.78
2018-01-01 04:00     7  2018-01-01     4    14.35
2018-01-01 05:00     8  2018-01-01     5    18.60
```

Comment: This will be still slower than parsing to datetime directly and needs 3 lines of code instead of one. :)

Comment: Yes definitely true

Comment: Still a nice answer and may be helpful for other cases, thus I gave it an upvote.